# How to SUM columns from three mysql tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

Here are my tables:

table1

```
-----------------
  ID   | value  
-----------------
  1    |   0    
-----------------    
  2    |   3  
----------------- 
  3    |  10  
-----------------
```

table2

```
-----------------
  ID   | value  
-----------------
  3    |   4    
----------------    
  5    |   6 
----------------- 
  6    |   8  
-----------------
```

table3

```
-----------------
  ID   | value  
-----------------
  7    |   7    
----------------    
  8    |   8
----------------- 
  9    |   9  
-----------------
```

result table

```
    -----------------
      ID   | value  
    -----------------
      1    |   0    
    ----------------    
      2    |   3 
    ----------------- 
      3    |   14  
   ----------------    
      5    |   6 
    ----------------- 
      6    |   8  
    -----------------
      7    |   7    
   ----------------    
      8    |   8
   ----------------- 
      9    |   9  
   -----------------
```

I'm wondering how to make a sum on `Value` column on `table1`, `table2` and ‍`table3` to reach the `Result` table?

The query that I've written is this:

```
INSERT INTO result (ID, value)
SELECT ID, SUM(t1.value+ t2.value, t3.value)
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3
GROUP BY ID
```

But it just hangs (the actual tables are large) and I doubt that it correct as `ID`s are not the same in table1 and table2

Comment: that is a cross join a.k.a. cartesian product, all permutations, on large tables. 1m x 1m =1 trillion

Comment: well actually it is an ambiguous error 1052, but ya get the idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to get the sum per id using `union all`

```
select id, sum(value) from (
    select id, value from table1
    union all select id, value from table2
    union all select id, value from table3
) t group by id
```

`union all` combines the results of each select statement into one big result (the `all` part makes sure duplicate rows are not automatically removed), and finally the combined result is grouped and summed as usual.

Comment: Nice. But what if there are 3 tables?

Comment: @Jand you can add additional `union all select ...` for additional tables

Comment: Sorry, I could not extend it to 3 tables, so just modified my question. Will you modify the answer please?

Comment: Worked like a charm, and very fast. Thank you!